# Printing Custom 2d Array as a Matrix

Tags: java, arrays, format, output

Given my current code, how could I output it in matrix format? My current output method simply lists the arrays in a straight line. However I need to stack them in their corresponding input parameters so a 3x3 input produces a 3x3 output. Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++){
    for( int column = 0; column < columns; column++){
        System.out.print(array2d[row][column] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This will print out a line of one row and then move onto the next row and print out its contents, etc... Tested with the code that you provided and works.

*EDIT* - Added the code for the way you wanted it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan =new Scanner(System.in); //creates scanner object

    System.out.println("How many rows to fill?"); //prompts user how many numbers they want to store in array
    int rows = scan.nextInt(); //takes input for response

    System.out.println("How many columns to fill?");
    int columns = scan.nextInt();
    int[][] array2d=new int[rows][columns]; //array for the elements

    for(int row=0;row<rows;row++) 
        for (int column=0; column < columns; column++)
        {
        System.out.println("Enter Element #" + row + column + ": "); //Stops at each element for next input
        array2d[row][column]=scan.nextInt(); //Takes in current input
        }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array2d));

    String[][] split = new String[1][rows];

    split[0] = (Arrays.deepToString(array2d)).split(Pattern.quote("], [")); //split at the comma

    for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++){
        System.out.println(split[0][row]);
    }

    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: Great thank you! Is there any way to do it with the Array.DeeptoString method I used originally? Just curious, I don't actually have to though

Comment: yes absolutely! split the `Arrays.deepToString(array2d)` at the `,` and put them into another array with size based on the number of rows of `array2d[][]`. Then use the same for loop logic to print it out. Let me know if you would like help with that. Accept my answer if it helped you out!

Comment: Okay i figured it out (although it looks kind of bad at the moment, you can figure out the formatting yourself ;)). It takes the `Arrays.deepToString(array2d)` and splits it and outputs. The line of interest to you is `split[0] = (Arrays.deepToString(array2d)).split(Pattern.quote("], ["));`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i =0; i < rows; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < columns ; j++) { 
        System.out.print(" " + array2d[i][j]); 
    } 
    System.out.println(""); 
}
```